# Peer-reviewed edit rejected without a trace

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users, rejected-edits

As a new user, I edited an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6736854/4940960 by updating outdated links, as well as adding a few lines of explanation.

As someone with very little points, the edit showed as needing peer-review. Within an hour the old answer re-appeared with no trace of my edit. This is clear-cut wrong in this case because the current links in the post are out-dated / not pointing to the intended locations. I did add a few lines of explanation as well, but even if these were not liked the up-to-date links should have been put through. Can anything be done about this?

Another issue is the lack of feedback, an edit rejection reason should be given and shown. And I have no idea who rejected the edit, is transparency not preferable?

Comment: It seems it was  more than an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8216631),you have changed nearly most of the details in question. What you changed are not only links.. However, my rep is 10 times less than reqd. to suggest edits!

Comment: @anshabhi I have lost the motivation to find (just) the up-to-date links again :o

Comment: @LongitudinalSynthesis they're all still listed in the rejected edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8216631) on [your activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4940960/longitudinal-synthesis?tab=activity) under all actions.  Your edit was narrowly rejected (2 approved, 3 rejected).  All three who rejected it chose the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the rejected edits area. At least updating links is clearly useful, would be much better to allow partial edits or edits of edits then (if the whole suggested edit is not to the liking of most). And I will not try to fight for the human element here, which is for the system to lean more towards acceptance rather than rejection (for close calls), because it is people behind these lines of text :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the rule is that reviewers can vote Approve or Reject, and the first category to get three votes wins. If one more Approver had snuck in, it would have been accepted. In any case, in the future, I'd suggest a more detailed edit comment. You edited more than just links, so you should mention that.